# validation on a textarea so it doesnt contain a specific special character with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a validation on my TextArea so my TextArea do not contain a specific special character such as " | " only.

I was trying something like this:

```
$('#CustomButton').click(function () {
if $("#CustomQuestionText").val()).indexOf('|') > -1) 
{
alert("The box has special characters. \nThese are not allowed.\n");
}
else
{
 my code here..
}
```

Any solutions is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have typo on your `if` statement, is that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$('#CustomButton').click(function () {
    if($("#CustomQuestionText").val().search('|')>=0){
    {
    alert("The box has special characters. \nThese are not allowed.\n");
    }
    else
    {
    my code here..
    }
});
```

Comment: If I want to do it on keypress how would it look like?

Comment: for your Comments @Obsivus:      $('#CustomQuestionText').keypress(function () {
    if($(this).val().search('|')>=0){
    {
    alert("The box has special characters. \nThese are not allowed.\n");
    }
    else
    {
    my code here..
    }
});